# Struggling to add alias at open new terminal in CentOS8

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, centos, alias

So I'm trying to create an alias to run two python scripts when a new bash window is opened but I keep running into odd issues.  If I create the alias manually in a terminal window, no problem:

```
alias UserPasswordReset="python3 /bin/Admin.py"
alias SystemFileCheck="python3 /bin/SystemFileCheck.py"
```

If I manually create a file called aliasfile.sh and put it in /etc/profile.d/ with of course #!/bin/bash as the first line, no problem when opening a new terminal the alias are there and work.

So here is the issue, if I pre-create the file and copy it into the /etc/profile.d/ directory I get strange results even though the contents of the file are exactly the same.  If I chmod the file to the same as the other in there it makes no difference.  This is the output I get

[image]

Not sure whats going on here or what I'm doing wrong, it should be such a simple thing to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want the aliases be automatically available for every user, you have to add the definitions in some global initialization file which will automatically source.

The problem here is that you need the aliases fo **interactive** shells, and the rules for interactive shells are a bit tricky. From the man-page:

*When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, it first reads and executes commands
from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and  executes  commands  from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.*

Hence, you have to source your `aliasfile.sh` in your `/etc/profile`. But this covers only the first case. For instance, if a user opens a interactive non-login shell, he would still not see the definitions. Since you are not permitted to hack the user's homedirectories, you better tell each use to also add a

```
. /path/to/setup/directory/aliasfile.sh
```

in his `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `. aliasfile.sh` to source the file. And also remove the shebgang line (`#!/bin/bash`) otherwise the alias will only be for the script.

Comment: Thanks, so I get the removing of the '#!/bin/bash', that's got rid the first error when opening a new terminal but don't understand the '. aliasfile.sh'. Do I rename the file to that? what is the '. alias' part and how do I implement it?

Comment: Simply run it at your command line (bash or sh or whatever you use).

Comment: @sportzpikachu : The #! line does not harm, if the file is sourced; it is simply useless. It still can be convenient if for editing a file a text editor is used which examines this line for doing the correct syntax colouring. However, another error in the file is that it (or another file sourced during bash startup) contains a carriage return character, as we can see from the error message.

Comment: That kind of defeats the object, the idea is that any user that opens a new terminal window will have these aliases available to use without any manual interaction. The .sh file in /etc/profile.d/ should auto add these alias for the user. Also I tried doing that but I still get that:

': [Errno 2] No such file or directoryileCheck.py

Error

Comment: Do you have a `.bashrc` `.profile`, or something like that? If so add the alias lines to that file, and it will get loaded on terminal startup.

Comment: OK, I think I may have worked a way around this, thanks for @sportzpikachu for pointing out the error is a carriage return. If I put the two alias in two separate one line files it works, not sure how I'm supposed to write a multiline file without a return carriage though.

Comment: @Dave748 : Lines are separated by a line feed character, since the very early beginning of Unix!!!! In very old Mac operating system (before they switched to BSD), the line separater was a carriage return.